# Paradox on non-stable equilibrium in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics

I have a question. I have read that there not stable places where a charge can oscillate in electrostatics. But I have come across with this problem of two equal possitive charges q separated by a distance d and in the middle a positive charge Q. Analyzing the problem I see that the force points towards the center whenever we displace the middle charge to left or right. In fact, by making and small displacement the total force on the middle charge is similar to the one on the harmonic oscillator. But this contradicts the theorem? Thanks

Comment: They are being pushed away. I understand. I mean by using other forces to fixed the charges $q$, the one in the middle can be stable, but just the three of them with just their electrostatic forces, they can not find stable equilibrium,right?

Comment: @Andrew What?? How does charges being fixed or not affect ${{\nabla}^2}V$ in a region not containing those charges? It is valid regardless. But in the given problem the charges are confined to be in a particular direction.

Comment: I do not understand. But in that case the charges of the extreme are not only confined 
in what dimension but the position itself.

Answer (score 0):

The theroem is valid for general space while in the mentioned case the charge is confined to move in one direction.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, please? I mean, the extreme charges are fixed and the one in the middle is stable. How the one in the middle can be stable comparing the the theorem? And besides, the oscillation can also be transversal if the charge in the middel is opposite, so that is more dimensions.